# Equivalent in Objective-c of AS3's getDefinitionByName?

Tags: objective-c, actionscript-3

Is there a way I can get/create a class in objective-c by using a String, like how I Can use getDefinitionByName in AS3 ?

Comment: You mean create a new class at runtime or get the `Class` of an existing class?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];`

from this thread:

[Create objective-c class instance by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for NSClassFromString. It should be used as such (I borrowed this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227085/nsclassfromstring-returns-nil); the code is from Dave DeLong):

```
Class dictionaryClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSMutableDictionary");
id object = [[dictionaryClass alloc] init];
[object setObject:@"Foo" forKey:@"Bar"];
```